# How to bandage my finger tip with an ulcer?

Tags: comfort

I am a 37 aged female, diagnosed with Scleroderma aka CREST.  It is a bit complicated to explain, but my body produce too much "calcium" under my nails that is very painful. If I get an ulcer, it will typically last 3-4 months.

Does anyone know a way to bandage my fingertip not covering completely?  The bandage should also be removable, because sometimes it is so sensitive that I can't even tolerate the bandage touching my skin.

I cannot get my hand wet, or touched or even stretch my fingers out. I expect the bandage to protect me from that occasional accidental bumps too. Direct AIR causes pain. At this point, I'm willing to try just about anything (rational of course) to try and at least tolerate the ulcer and keep it protected from germs. I will be forever thankful to anyone with ANY reply.

[image: active ulcer in index fingertip]
[image: Scleroderma and Raynaud's]

Comment: Zee, your bandaging challenge is interesting but unfortunately, medical advice seeking "hacks about this illness" is outside the scope of *this* site. I trimmed your question down to the issue about the bandage. You may want to check out our Health site to see if the remainder of your question is on topic there. See their [Help Center](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) to see if would be on topic. Sorry about the confusion. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks you for your time and adadviceI will definately look over the Health site.

Comment: The suggested answers are good, perhaps as an additional measure to protect from water and air, maybe carefully apply something along the lines of Rose Hip oil balm or any other soother type balm such as lavender

Answer (score 2):

You could use a finger guard/protector/thimble (as used in sewing). Keep it in place with bandaging tape. When you need to use water, put on gloves that are large enough to fit over the finger guard.

Comment: I think this is a good answer but a photo that illustrates your solution would make it much better.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of a bandage, a finger splint (you can find them at a pharmacy) would work. There's a wide variety of them, so you should be able to find one that will protect the fingertip from bumps without putting pressure on it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would try a combination of a [finger cot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_cot) which is basically a single finger rubber 'glove' and a chusioning layer of soft fabric around it.
Or, if it suits you better, have the soft fabric on the inside and the rubber in a bigger size on the outside.

[image: finger cot]
*Finger cot as used on the Wikipedia page*, full attribution [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Fingercot.jpg)

I would fold a bit of teddycloth (like a towel) and sew both sides to make a one finger mitten and use that with the protection against getting wet. But any piece of cloth which is big enough can be wrapped around the finger in the way you find least painfull.

If needed (likely) you will need a bit of sticky plaster to keep them in place but this will be much lower down the finger. And you can use different length of mits and gloves against each other to move the spot you need to attach the tape.

In case you need the sturdy protection the other answers recomment, you can still use the finger cot to protect your finger from getting wet.

Finger cots should be available from the same shops as plasters, or from (web)shops that supply work places that work with food, as they are often used to protect damaged fingers and food from each other.
They come in several sizes, you might want to go for the bigger ones.